# django 2 - Nested query based off multiple models

Tags: python, django, python-3.6

Update: See bottom.

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to achieve a nested/chained query based on my needs.  There might be a better way to get the results I need so please let me know.

Trying to get the authenticated user and get a list of friends, which I have working and I get a queryset object of friends.  I would like to pass the queryset object of friends into another query that searches the Post model, matches the username found Friend.users to the Post.creator so I get back another queryset which will have all the Posts of all my friends which I can display in the template.

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner_friend', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=None, null=True)
```

EDIT:

I'm trying to do this with my code

```
f = Friend.objects.all().filter(owner__username='admin').filter(users__username='jeff')
```

output

```
<QuerySet [<Friend: Friend object (1)>]>


p = Post.objects.all().filter(creator__username__in=f)
```

ValueError: Cannot use QuerySet for "Friend": Use a QuerySet for "User".

Thanks for the help.

**Update 1:**

I've changed my models to use ForeignKeys instead.  I've been using the shell to test and I'm getting an unexpected result, see below.

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_friend', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner_friend', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

f = Friend.objects.filter(owner__username='admin').values_list('users__username', flat=True)
```

Output

```
<QuerySet ['jeff', 'sam']>



Post.objects.filter(creator__username__in=list(f))
```

Output

```
<QuerySet []>
```

If I put in the list manually

```
Post.objects.filter(creator__username__in=['admin', 'jeff'])
```

Output

```
<QuerySet [<Post: Post Title 1>]>
```

I think if I can get the __in=list(f) to work this should fix the issue.

**Update 2**

list(f) is actually working, I didn't have a Post linked for the user accounts for the friends being pulled through.  Once I created the post for the friends, I'm now getting a queryset.

I'm not sure what I'm doing is the best way but it's working.

For future readers I hope this helps.

Comment: Why don't you directly add a `friends` field to `User`?

Answer (score 0):

The Friend model is a bit strange and is causing you some difficulty. Really, Friend should be the through table in the many-to-many relationship between User and itself. Presumably you are using the built-in User model, which is why you have used an external model; but you can still simulate a through table with two foreign keys:

```
class Friend(models.Model):
    from_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='users_from', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='users_to', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now your query can be:

```
Post.objects.filter(creator__users_to__from_user__username='admin')
```

that is, give me all Posts whose creator is on the "to_user" side of the friend relationship where the from_user's username is "admin".

Comment: I've updated my models to use ForeignKey so no more M2M.  I've come across a path forward and I will update my post to reflect that but I hit another issue.